# Javascript fabric.js and prototype

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

In an example about Fabric.js available at: http://fabricjs.com/interaction-with-objects-outside-canvas

The 3rd line reads:
fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

The property transparentCorners is already a property of the fabric.Object. We are NOT adding it here.

Why is there a need to add the word "prototype"?  I don't get the reason. Since we are NOT adding a new property to fabric.Object, wouldn't be the same to write:
fabric.Object.transparentCorners = false;

Please explain the difference.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the property ( modifying the value of the property ) on the fabric.Object prototype allows you to get that property set for each instance of the object and objects extended from that one already set to that default value.

So each fabric.Rect and fabric.Triangle will have the property transparentCorners set to false.

Comment: Hi and thank you 

What is the difference then between:
fabric.Canvas.prototype.selection = false;
AND
fabric.Canvas.selection = false;

Basically with or without the "prototype" word?

Comment: One set to the prototype. So each new instance of Canvas will have that property set to false. The other does not really change anything since fabric.Canvas is a function not an object.